# GPS Data with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, gps, nmea

I'm working in a project where I have to collect data from a GPS Module (NMEA data) and pass it to an html application so I can display exact location of the device on a Google map. I have created the map using the google maps api but I'm unsure of how to pass the NMEA data through my application. What would be the most efficient way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you having trouble sending data from a server to a web-based client?  Parsing NMEA sentences?  What are you having trouble with, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Google's My Maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/about/mymaps/) ([this is a very easy method to get your own map in your own HTML page](https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/learn/visualize-your-data-on-a-custom-map-using-google-my-maps/)) you can import GPX data straight into the map. You just need to convert your NMEA data to GPX.

If you're comfortable with the command line [GPSBabel](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GPSBabel) looks relatively simple to use (there are a couple of GUIs available if needed). Alternatively, OpenStreetMap has [some other alternative methods that you can try](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Converting/NMEA_to_GPX).